# GLEW - cmake and clion - undefined reference

Tags: opengl, cmake, mingw, glew, clion

I am trying to link glew and glfw on clion with cmake. I did it with visual studio easilly, but I am having problems with clion. This is how I have included my dependencies like glew (.dll shouldnt be there I guess):

[image]

And this is my cmake file.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(Course)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/GLFW/include)
link_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/GLFW/libs)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/GLEW/include)
link_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/GLEW/libs)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp Window.cpp Window.h)
add_executable(Course ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(Course ${OPENGL_LIBRARY} libglew32.a libglfw3.a )
```

Error:

```
C:/Users/Onur/Documents/MEGA/workspace/cpp/Course/Dependencies/GLEW/libs\libglew32.a(glew.o):glew.c:(.text+0x42c): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
C:/Users/Onur/Documents/MEGA/workspace/cpp/Course/Dependencies/GLEW/libs\libglew32.a(glew.o):glew.c:(.text+0x448): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
C:/Users/Onur/Documents/MEGA/workspace/cpp/Course/Dependencies/GLEW/libs\libglew32.a(glew.o):glew.c:(.text+0x464): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
C:/Users/Onur/Documents/MEGA/workspace/cpp/Course/Dependencies/GLEW/libs\libglew32.a(glew.o):glew.c:(.text+0x478): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
C:/Users/Onur/Documents/MEGA/workspace/cpp/Course/Dependencies/GLEW/libs\libglew32.a(glew.o):glew.c:(.text+0x48c): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
C:/Users/Onur/Documents/MEGA/workspace/cpp/Course/Dependencies/GLEW/libs\libglew32.a(glew.o):glew.c:(.text+0x4a0): more undefined references to `wglGetProcAddress@4' follow
C:/Users/Onur/Documents/MEGA/workspace/cpp/Course/Dependencies/GLEW/libs\libglew32.a(glew.o):glew.c:(.text+0x1de1f): undefined reference to `wglGetCurrentDC@0'
C:/Users/Onur/Documents/MEGA/workspace/cpp/Course/Dependencies/GLEW/libs\libglew32.a(glew.o):glew.c:(.text+0x1de8f): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
C:/Users/Onur/Documents/MEGA/workspace/cpp/Course/Dependencies/GLEW/libs\libglew32.a(glew.o):glew.c:(.text+0x1dea3): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
C:/Users/Onur/Documents/MEGA/workspace/cpp/Course/Dependencies/GLEW/libs\libglew32.a(glew.o):glew.c:(.text+0x1debe): undefined reference to `wglGetCurrentDC@0'
C:/Users/Onur/Documents/MEGA/workspace/cpp/Course/Dependencies/GLEW/libs\libglew32.a(glew.o):glew.c:(.text+0x1df3a): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
C:/Users/Onur/Documents/MEGA/workspace/cpp/Course/Dependencies/GLEW/libs\libglew32.a(glew.o):glew.c:(.text+0x1e0c0): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
C:/Users/Onur/Documents/MEGA/workspace/cpp/Course/Dependencies/GLEW/libs\libglew32.a(glew.o):glew.c:(.text+0x1e0dc): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
C:/Users/Onur/Documents/MEGA/workspace/cpp/Course/Dependencies/GLEW/libs\libglew32.a(glew.o):glew.c:(.text+0x1e0fa): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
C:/Users/Onur/Documents/MEGA/workspace/cpp/Course/Dependencies/GLEW/libs\libglew32.a(glew.o):glew.c:(.text+0x1e4dc): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
C:/Users/Onur/Documents/MEGA/workspace/cpp/Course/Dependencies/GLEW/libs\libglew32.a(glew.o):glew.c:(.text+0x1e4f8): more undefined references to `wglGetProcAddress@4' follow
C:/Users/Onur/Documents/MEGA/workspace/cpp/Course/Dependencies/GLEW/libs\libglew32.a(glew.o):glew.c:(.text+0x20352): undefined reference to `glGetString@4'
C:/Users/Onur/Documents/MEGA/workspace/cpp/Course/Dependencies/GLEW/libs\libglew32.a(glew.o):glew.c:(.text+0x204d4): undefined reference to `glGetIntegerv@8'
C:/Users/Onur/Documents/MEGA/workspace/cpp/Course/Dependencies/GLEW/libs\libglew32.a(glew.o):glew.c:(.text+0x204e3): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
C:/Users/Onur/Documents/MEGA/workspace/cpp/Course/Dependencies/GLEW/libs\libglew32.a(glew.o):glew.c:(.text+0x2055e): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
C:/Users/Onur/Documents/MEGA/workspace/cpp/Course/Dependencies/GLEW/libs\libglew32.a(glew.o):glew.c:(.text+0x2057a): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
C:/Users/Onur/Documents/MEGA/workspace/cpp/Course/Dependencies/GLEW/libs\libglew32.a(glew.o):glew.c:(.text+0x20596): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
C:/Users/Onur/Documents/MEGA/workspace/cpp/Course/Dependencies/GLEW/libs\libglew32.a(glew.o):glew.c:(.text+0x205ac): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
C:/Users/Onur/Documents/MEGA/workspace/cpp/Course/Dependencies/GLEW/libs\libglew32.a(glew.o):glew.c:(.text+0x20665): more undefined references to `wglGetProcAddress@4' follow
C:/Users/Onur/Documents/MEGA/workspace/cpp/Course/Dependencies/GLEW/libs\libglew32.a(glew.o):glew.c:(.text+0x26e21): undefined reference to `glGetString@4'
C:/Users/Onur/Documents/MEGA/workspace/cpp/Course/Dependencies/GLEW/libs\libglew32.a(glew.o):glew.c:(.text+0x26f31): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
C:/Users/Onur/Documents/MEGA/workspace/cpp/Course/Dependencies/GLEW/libs\libglew32.a(glew.o):glew.c:(.text+0x26f47): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
C:/Users/Onur/Documents/MEGA/workspace/cpp/Course/Dependencies/GLEW/libs\libglew32.a(glew.o):glew.c:(.text+0x26f60): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
C:/Users/Onur/Documents/MEGA/workspace/cpp/Course/Dependencies/GLEW/libs\libglew32.a(glew.o):glew.c:(.text+0x26f7b): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
C:/Users/Onur/Documents/MEGA/workspace/cpp/Course/Dependencies/GLEW/libs\libglew32.a(glew.o):glew.c:(.text+0x26f8f): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
C:/Users/Onur/Documents/MEGA/workspace/cpp/Course/Dependencies/GLEW/libs\libglew32.a(glew.o):glew.c:(.text+0x26fa3): more undefined references to `wglGetProcAddress@4' follow
```

Seems like cmake can't find glew (but I told it where glew is?):
[image]

Edit:

**Adding  ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} at the end of target_link_libraries worked**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(Course)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/GLFW/include)
link_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/GLFW/libs)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/GLEW/include/GL)
link_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/GLEW/libs)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp Window.cpp Window.h)
add_executable(Course ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(Course glfw3.a libglew32.a ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: Provide error message, please. BTW, according to [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindOpenGL.html), `find_package(OpenGL)` sets `OPENGL_LIBRARIES` variable (plural form), not an `OPENGL_LIBRARY`.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: So, what about replacing *OPENGL_LIBRARY* with *OPENGL_LIBRARIES*? `Seems like cmake can't find glew` - You code doesn't instruct CMake to find GLEW. Probably, this cached variable is created by previous version of your project. Remove build directory, and build project again.

Comment: Got it working. Had to link libopengl32.a like this:
target_link_libraries(Course glfw3.a libglew32.a libopengl32.a)

Comment: But why isnt find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED) not working?

Comment: `But why isnt find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED) not working?` It **works**. But you don't use its results (*OPENGL_LIBRARIES* variable).

Comment: Damn I tried OPENGL_LIBRARIES first and it didn't work because I had wrong order like this: target_link_libraries(Course  ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} glfw3.a libglew32.a)
 then I tried this: target_link_libraries(Course glfw3.a libglew32.a ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})
 and it works too!